# Present UIAlertController from NSOperation

Tags: objective-c, ios8, nsoperation, uialertcontroller

What I tried is:

```
- (void)main
{
    NSError *err = (__bridge NSError *)error;
                    UIAlertController * alert = [UIAlertController
                                                 alertControllerWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Error", nil)
                                                 message:err.localizedDescription
                                                 preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];


                    UIAlertAction* ok = [UIAlertAction
                                         actionWithTitle:@"OK"
                                         style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                                         handler:^(UIAlertAction * action)
                                         {
                                             //Do some thing here
                                            [self.window.rootViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
                                         }];
...
}
```

The problem is that there is no access to `self.window` in my `NSOperation` subclass.
Is there any other way to present alert controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UIApplicationDelegate` instance keeps window object, so you can get it and use for your purposes.

```
  [[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate window]
```

Also `[UIApplication sharedApplication]` provides other methods which you may be useful to you:

- `- windows` - an array of all the windows;
- `– keyWindow` - gives the window that is receiving keyboard input (or nil);

If you are not creating additional windows, then using `[[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate window]` will be fine.

Comment: Will it be ```[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow]``` for iOS?

Comment: oops, sorry, I thought it's OSX, I will edit my post now